# How to correctly specify package in Junit WildcardPatternSuite and @SuiteClasses

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to run JUnit tests in a specific package but can't seem to get it quite right.

This line works:

```
@SuiteClasses({ "**/*IntegrationTest.class" })
```

But none of the following seem to work giving "Did not find any *.class file using the specified wildcard patterns"

How do I get just the tests in the subfolders of the omop folder to execute?

```
// @SuiteClasses({ "**/omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "./omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "omop/**/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
```

[image]

Here's the entire test class:

```
package org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.sql.Connection;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.tools.populate.PopulateOmopInstanceFromFhirFiles;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.util.db.connection.OmopDatabaseConnectionFactory;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.util.db.counts.GetCountForTable;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.util.db.truncatedatatables.TruncateAllDataTables;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.util.mapping.impl.cache.MappedConceptCache;
import org.nachc.tools.fhirtoomop.util.mapping.impl.cache.StandardConceptCache;
import org.yaorma.util.time.Timer;

import com.googlecode.junittoolbox.SuiteClasses;
import com.googlecode.junittoolbox.WildcardPatternSuite;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
// @SuiteClasses({ "**/*IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "**/omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "./omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "omop/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })
// @SuiteClasses({ "omop/**/**/*.IntegrationTest.class" })

public class RunAllIntegrationTests {

    private static Timer TIMER = new Timer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        TIMER.start();
        log.info("***********************************************************");
        log.info("Starting set up");
        log.info("***********************************************************");
        log.info("Truncating tables...");
        TruncateAllDataTables.exec();
        log.info("Done truncating tables.");
        Connection conn = OmopDatabaseConnectionFactory.getOmopConnection();
        try {
            MappedConceptCache.init(conn);
            StandardConceptCache.init(conn);
        } finally {
            OmopDatabaseConnectionFactory.close(conn);
        }
        log.info("***********************************************************");
        log.info("Done with set up");
        log.info("***********************************************************");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanup() {
        log.info("");
        log.info("");
        log.info("Truncating data tables...");
        TruncateAllDataTables.exec();
        log.info("Populating with patients using config file (PopulateOmopInstanceFromFhirFiles)...");
        new PopulateOmopInstanceFromFhirFiles().exec();
        log.info("");
        log.info("");
        log.info("***********************************************************");
        log.info("* * * ");
        log.info("* * * Done with integration tests.");
        log.info("* * *");
        log.info("***********************************************************");
        log.info("");
        TIMER.stop();
        log.info("Start:   " + TIMER.getStartAsString());
        log.info("Stop:    " + TIMER.getStopAsString());
        log.info("Elapsed: " + TIMER.getElapsedString());
        log.info("");
        int patientCount = GetCountForTable.exec("person");
        log.info("There are now " + patientCount + " patients in your OMOP database.");
        int connCount = OmopDatabaseConnectionFactory.getConnectionCount();
        log.info("Open connections after tear down: " + connCount);
        assertTrue(connCount == 0);
        log.info("");
        log.info("Done.");
    }

    public static void exec() {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(RunAllIntegrationTests.class);
        System.out.println("Finished. Result: Failures: " +
                result.getFailureCount() + ". Ignored: " +
                result.getIgnoreCount() + ". Tests run: " +
                result.getRunCount() + ". Time: " +
                result.getRunTime() + "ms.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this did not work previously.  The following runs only tests in the omop dir and sub dir correctly:

```
@SuiteClasses({ "omop/**/*IntegrationTest.class" })
```